# Webkit Transformations, Translate after rotation

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, webkit, translate-animation

I have been working on rather simple webkit transforms to create (layman's) animations. I'm doing pretty good except for one issue, on which I'm yet to find some info. Here goes:

Description: I have a rectangular div, that I rotate by 90 degrees, using target.style.webkitTransform += 'rotateZ(90deg)'; which is fine - and I translate it using target.style.webkitTransform += 'translate3d(50px, 0px, 0px)';

Problem: When you rotate, the axis of the element also rotates and if you translate (for example) in x-axis, the object will move in the new direction (that the element is facing towards) e.g. 50 px downwards in the example above (after the rotation).

I need a way to recalculate/reset the axis (without changing the rotation) so that the animation makes sense for a lay man i.e. For programmers it's easy to see that the object is facing in a different direction but for non-techie user left will always remain left.

The requirement: When the user says move it 50px on x-axis it should move 50px on x-axis (for the user) regardless of rotation or any other transform applied to it beforehand.

Further: I'll not know in advance how the user will manipulate an object hence I can't take fixed values and work around them, hence the need for a formula to recalculate/reset everything given the object's style properties and construct further transforms.

Comment: Couldn't you move the element with top and left properties (and position absolute or relative) ?

Comment: That's not an option for two reasons:
1- I don't want to mess with top and left for I will be giving options to slide the element back in as well. In which case I can either store initial position and last position for each transform or I just work with offset positions.
2- using left and top properties results in jerky animations on devices, transforms are way smoother - more so when you have many elements of relatively larger sizes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're appending the `translate()` to the end of the transform, then it should translate by exactly what you specified, independent of any previous rotations.

Comment: I am appending it except that it doesn't make any difference, whether I use translate or translate3d

Comment: Editing the question to make it more comprehensible.

Comment: Ah, indeed.  The problem is that you want to transform an object position whereas CSS 2d transforms transform coordinate systems...  Your options are either to put the translate first (so it's happening in the untransformed page coordinate system) or manually compute the right translate value for the currently transformed coordinates to achieve the page-relative effect you want.... (effectively inverting the linear part of the current transformation matrix, then multiplying that inverse by your desired translation to get the thing you stick in `translate()`).

Comment: I just started getting into matrices, I'll keep posted if I get somewhere. Meanwhile, anyone worked on such an issue (and/or solved it via matrices), please do post away! I'll put up my pages on a blog or a server once I'm done, so others may benefit!
@Boris, thanks for your replies!